# Getting creation date of image files on a path

Tags: powershell, wmic

I have to get the creation time of image files saved on a folder (around 4500 files) in milliseconds to evaluate errors and delays in a telescope instrumentation set up. The normal file attributes give out the time only in seconds, but WMIC gives a more precise time. I can get the creation time of a single file using

```
wmic datafile where "Name=''C:\\Users\\...\\test\\test.fit'" get creationdate
```

But when I change the where clause to get creationdate of all files, I get either invalid query or no instances found. I use the following command:

```
wmic datafile where "path='C:\\Users\\...\\test\\'" get creationdate
```

The path does not have spaces in it. What is the source of 'No instances available' error when using Where clause with path?

I tried changing the double and single quotation marks, and testing on a shorter test path and different file formats. But it did not change the result.

Comment: Do not use `wmic` in PowerShell unless you're hard-pressed for performance. The PoSh way of getting the creation time of files is `Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\...\test' | Select-Object -Expand CreationTime` or `ls 'C:\Users\...\test' | select -exp CreationTime`.

Comment: Also the default format doesn't ***output*** milliseconds while they are of course present, just use a format string to include them `| Select-Object @{n='CreationTime';e={$_.CreationTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff')}}`

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment:

> Also the default format doesn't output milliseconds while they are of course present, just use a format string to include them

```
| Select-Object @{n='CreationTime';e={$_.CreationTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff')}}
```

wmic outputs a different time stripped off the DST (daylight savings time) information.

```
> Get-Item C:\test\foo.zip| Select-Object Name,CreationTime

Name    CreationTime
----    ------------
foo.zip 2019-07-29 19:18:00
```

---

```
> wmic datafile where "Name='C:\\test\\foo.zip'" get creationdate
CreationDate
20190729181800.928368+060
```

---

```
> gi C:\test\foo.zip| Select @{n='CreationTime';e={$_.CreationTime.ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss.ffffffzzz')}}

CreationTime
------------
20190729191800.928368+02:00
```

Answer (score 0):

This Batch script is just used to create a `.csv file` with the delimiter `;` with those informations :

`"File name";"File path";"The date of creation of this file"`

```bat
@echo off
mode con cols=70 lines=3 & Color 0A
Title Get FilePath with their CreationDate by Hackoo 2019
Set "Target_dir=%userprofile%\Pictures\AutoSaveScreenShot\"
REM IMPORTANT Don't forget the final backslash in the path of your folder\
Call :Check_backslash %Target_dir% Target_dir
Set "LogFile=%~dpn0.csv"
If Exist "%LogFile%" Del "%LogFile%"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ('Dir "%Target_dir%" /s /b /o:n /ad') do (
    REM Set "Drive=%%a"
    REM IMPORTANT Don't forget the final backslash in the path of your folder\
    Set "Folder_Path=%%b\"
    Call :Check_backslash !Folder_Path! Folder_Path
    Call :Add_backSlash !Folder_Path! Folder_Path
    @For /f "Tokens=1,2 Skip=1 Delims= " %%a in ('WMIC DATAFILE WHERE "PATH='!Folder_Path!'" GET CreationDate^,Caption') do (
    REM The output of WMIC is unicode !
    REM The trailing <CR> can be removed by passing the value through another FOR /F loop.
    REM This also removes the phantom "blank" line (actually a <CR>) ie The second for /f loop
        @For /f "delims=" %%f in ("%%a") do (
            Set "FileName=%%~nxa"
            Set "FilePath=%%a"
            set "DT=%%b"
            REM Convert ISO date to Date
            set "DT=!DT:~0,4!_!DT:~4,2!_!DT:~6,2!_!DT:~8,2!-!DT:~10,2!-!DT:~12,2!"
            Call :Scanning "!FileName!"
            echo "!FileName!";"!FilePath!";"!DT!">>"!LogFile!"
        )
    )
)
If Exist "!LogFile!" Start "" /MAX Notepad "!LogFile!" & Exit
::---------------------------------------------------------------------
:Add_backSlash <String> <Var to Set>
Rem Subroutine to replace the simple "\" by a double "\\" into a String
Set "MyString=%1"
Set "String=\"
Set "NewString=\\"
Call Set "%2=%%MyString:%String%=%NewString%%%"
Exit /b
::---------------------------------------------------------------------
:Check_backslash
Set "datapath=%1"
IF NOT "%datapath:~-1%"=="\" SET "%2=%datapath%\"
Exit /b
::---------------------------------------------------------------------
:Scanning <file>
Cls & Color 0A
echo(
echo                  "%~1"  ...
goto :eof
::---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, the Output file is like this one :

> ```
> "Capture_06_04_2018_08_38_28.gif";"c:\users\hackoo\pictures\autosavescreenshot\2018-04\capture_06_04_2018_08_38_28.gif";"2018_04_06_08-38-28"
> "Capture_06_04_2018_08_39_29.png";"c:\users\hackoo\pictures\autosavescreenshot\2018-04\capture_06_04_2018_08_39_29.png";"2018_04_06_08-39-29"
> "Capture_06_04_2018_08_41_22.jpeg";"c:\users\hackoo\pictures\autosavescreenshot\2018-04\capture_06_04_2018_08_41_22.jpeg";"2018_04_06_08-41-22"
> "Capture_06_04_2018_08_44_36.png";"c:\users\hackoo\pictures\autosavescreenshot\2018-04\capture_06_04_2018_08_44_36.png";"2018_04_06_08-44-51"
> "Capture_06_04_2018_14_43_09.jpg";"c:\users\hackoo\pictures\autosavescreenshot\2018-04\capture_06_04_2018_14_43_09.jpg";"2018_04_06_14-43-09"
> "Capture_06_04_2018_14_46_53.png";"c:\users\hackoo\pictures\autosavescreenshot\2018-04\capture_06_04_2018_14_46_53.png";"2018_04_06_14-47-02"
> "Capture_06_04_2018_14_47_12.png";"c:\users\hackoo\pictures\autosavescreenshot\2018-04\capture_06_04_2018_14_47_12.png";"2018_04_06_14-47-19"
> "Capture_07_04_2018_02_44_53.jpg";"c:\users\hackoo\pictures\autosavescreenshot\2018-04\capture_07_04_2018_02_44_53.jpg";"2018_04_07_02-44-53"
> ```